# Compile with -fopenmp solves compilation problem but results in gsl_vector_double.h:180: ERROR: index out of range when call apop_estimate

Tags: c, gsl

I am unable to run any program with the `apop_estimate(data, model)` function.

On execution I get the error:

```
$ ./census
gsl: ../gsl/gsl_vector_double.h:180: ERROR: index out of range

Default GSL error handler invoked.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I run `gdb` I get the following:

```
Reading symbols from census...

(gdb) r

Starting program: /home/Colin/Documents/intro-apophenia/census

[New Thread 19156.0x4584]

[New Thread 19156.0x43f4]

[New Thread 19156.0x49ac]

[New Thread 19156.0x4904]

gsl: ../gsl/gsl_vector_double.h:180: ERROR: index out of range

Default GSL error handler invoked.



Thread 1 "census" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

0x0000000077c297ea in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll

(gdb) bt

#0  0x0000000077c297ea in ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll

#1  0x000007fefda110dc in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll

#2  0x000007feb97300d0 in sigfillset () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll

#3  0x000007feb972bbbb in sched_getscheduler () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll

#4  0x000007feb972bfc5 in sched_getscheduler () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll

#5  0x000007feb98868d8 in cygwin1!abort () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll

#6  0x00000003eef65ba7 in gsl_error () from /usr/bin/cyggsl-19.dll

#7  0x00000003ef0b259f in gsl_vector_get () from /usr/bin/cyggsl-19.dll

#8  0x00000001004296d4 in ols_log_likelihood (d=0xa00036c50, p=<optimized out>) at apop_ols.c:166

#9  0x000000010041a336 in apop_log_likelihood (d=<optimized out>, m=<optimized out>) at apop_model.c:268

#10 0x000000010042ae23 in apop_estimate_OLS (inset=<optimized out>, ep=0xa00030300) at apop_ols.c:341

#11 0x000000010041a19f in apop_estimate (d=0xa00036c50, m=<optimized out>) at apop_model.c:240

#12 0x0000000100401180 in main ()
```

The program `census.c` is exactly as per the [apophenia website](http://apophenia.info/gentle.html), a gentle introduction section.

```cpp
#include <apop.h>

int main(){

    apop_text_to_db(.text_file="ss08pdc.csv", .tabname="dc");

    apop_data *data = apop_query_to_data("select log(pincp+10) as log_income, agep, sex "
                                         "from dc where agep+ pincp+sex is not null and pincp>=0");

    apop_model *est = apop_estimate(data, apop_ols);

    apop_model_print(est);
}
```

I tried commenting out the code in `gsl_vector_double.h` that calls the error.

```cpp
INLINE_FUN
double gsl_vector_get(const gsl_vector * v, const size_t i) {

#if GSL_RANGE_CHECK
  if (GSL_RANGE_COND(i >= v->size)) {
    GSL_ERROR_VAL ("index out of range", GSL_EINVAL, 0);
  }
#endif

  return v->data[i * v->stride];
}
```

After commenting all but the return line in the body of the above code, re-compiling and calling the executable I got the exact same error about index out of range.

I tried using a very small dataset in the call to `apop_estimate`.  No effect.

I tried running `gdb` and investigating local variables in frames.  Unable to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: There is a two-year-old [issue](https://github.com/b-k/apophenia/issues/43) (including a workaround) about this on their GitHub page... The library doesn't seem to be maintained anymore. The issue probably doesn't have anything to do with using `-fopenmp`, which is the right thing to do here.

Comment: Trying to change the GSL code seems like a bad idea, as it will just cause undefined behavior or a segmentation fault when you access an out-of-range index. The range check is there to help you figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I agree that commenting out the code in gsl_vector_double.h is a bad idea.  The issue reported by chplr is not quite the same as mine.  He reports that the code compiles but gives a runtime error.  In my case the code does not compile without the -fopenmp option.  I tried the workaround proposed by JaoquinglesiasTurina, i.e., made the changes to line 166 in file apop_ols.c, recompiled using the same options as chplr but also with -fopenmp (it would not compile otherwise).  This gave the same warnings he reports.  In my case on running I again got the same index out of range error.

Comment: Like a said, `-fopenmp` is not an issue. According to the linker error that you got without it, Apophenia uses OpenMP library calls inside, so you need to tell the linker to use it as well. That most probably has nothing at all to do with the issue at hand. Looking at the repository again, it looks like you can configure and build Apophenia without OpenMP. I doubt that this will solve your actual problem though. Did you rebuild Apophenia after implementing the workaround? Recompiling the sample wont be enough.

Comment: No I did no rebuild Apophenia after the workaround.  The apophenia package is not available on Cygwin and I found the process of building it in the first place quite a challenge - one I would prefer not to repeat if I can possibly avoid it.

Comment: Well I don't know if it was a broadly used package at some point (doesn't look like it with 190 Stars on GitHub), but it seems pretty dead to me. Maybe you can ask for an alternative on the [Software Recommendations StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).